# Why did the IP Source change after ICMP passed through the Linux bridge?

Tags: linux, docker, internet

I created a bridge br0 and veth(v0 and v1), But they are not interoperable. tcpdump shows that the IP Source of ICMP has changed. When Mask is /24, they will be interoperable. thanks for your help.

```
[root@VM-12-6-centos ~]# ip netns exec n1 ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
1147: v0@if1146: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 46:39:b5:cf:bd:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.2/16 scope global v0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4439:b5ff:fecf:bdb6/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@VM-12-6-centos ~]# ip netns exec n2 ip addr 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 
1149: v1@if1148: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:c0:82:05:6f:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.3/16 scope global v1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::54c0:82ff:fe05:6f7d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 

[root@VM-12-6-centos ~]# ip netns exec n2 ping 192.168.0.2 
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data. ^C
--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics --- 
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 81ms

[root@VM-12-6-centos ~]# ip netns exec n1 tcpdump -ni v0 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode listening on v0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes 
23:49:35.395270 IP 10.0.12.6 > 192.168.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 7989, seq 1, length 64 23:49:40.562143 ARP, Request who-has
192.168.0.2 tell 192.168.0.3, length 28 23:49:40.562154 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.2 is-at 46:39:b5:cf:bd:b6, length 28

[root@VM-12-6-centos ~]# route -n Kernel IP routing table Destination  Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.12.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.12.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cni0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-3f74298c82df
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-447c96a995be

[root@VM-12-6-centos ~]# brctl show bridge name     bridge id          STP enabled     interfaces br-3f74298c82df         8000.0242cacea67f   no              vethf4618dd br-447c96a995be         8000.024273831baf  no              vethbf5d89d br0             8000.7ae1f3216832       no br-v0
                                                        br-v1 cni0            8000.52bc6b3b510e       no              veth0f9960a8
                                                        veth1cd3811c
                                                        veth2a89c6ed
                                                        veth3aeb1ce7
                                                        vethca9494e3 docker0         8000.0242fcf19461       no docker_gwbridge        
8000.02420fc41a90       no              veth85a243e
                                                        vethd1cfb42
```

Answer (score 1):

For everything to work you need to create 2 pairs of `veth` pipes. At one end they must be included in the bridge. The bridge and the ends of the veth interfaces are located in the root network namespace. Other ends of pipes v1 and v2 are in namespace n1 and namespace n2 respectively. Example:

```
ip netns add n1
ip netns add n2
```

The ends included in the bridge will be called bv1 and bv2:

```
ip link add v1 netns n1 type veth peer name bv1
ip link add v2 netns n2 type veth peer name bv2
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set bv1 master br0
ip link set bv2 master br0
ip link set bv1 up
ip link set bv2 up
```

```
brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.d2dba1636571   no          bv1
                                        bv2
```

Go to n1:

```
nsenter --net=/var/run/netns/n1
ip addr add 192.168.0.2/16 dev v1
ip link set v1 up
ip link set lo up
exit
```

Go to n2:

```
nsenter --net=/var/run/netns/n2
ip addr add 192.168.0.3/16 dev v2
ip link set v2 up
ip link set lo up
exit
```

Result:

```
ip netns exec n1 ping -c2 -I v1 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.265 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms

ip netns exec n2 ping -c2 -I v2 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.195 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.227 ms
```

Comment: To check, I reconnected the interfaces to the docker bridge - it still works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I found the reason, it was docker's iptables rules that were interfering with his normal work

Comment: You can check: `sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0`

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information in the question for a definite answer, but:

You have a ton of other interfaces in the bridge, and you mention Docker. Very likely the ping packet you are seeing comes from something in Docker, and is not the ping you made. That's why "the source IP changed" (it didn't change, it's a completely different ping).

Verify this by making your bridge and veth on a system without docker. You also need to run the tcpdump in a second terminal, it has to run while you make the ping.

Another option is that one of the many iptables-rules Docker has actually influences your ping, and **does** change the source address, for whatever reason.

---

TL;DR: If you are running docker, **don't** try to meddle with the network. You'll have a hard time to get anything to work, and even if you get it to work, it can break again the next time Docker updates its iptables rules.

If you need a direct network between two containers, use an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/), and it'll take five minutes to do that with [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks).

---

From https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/, per comment, emphasis mine:

> On Linux, Docker manipulates iptables rules to provide network isolation. While this is an implementation detail and **you should not modify the rules Docker inserts** into your iptables policies, it does have some implications on what you need to do if you want to have **your own policies in addition** to those managed by Docker.

This means in particular anything attached to the bridge Docker uses will fall under the Docker iptables rules, which you **shouldn't modify**.

You can have your own policies for anything that's completely independent of the Docker network, but meddling with the way Docker does networking isn't something I'd recommend.

And this means if you want to have networking between Docker containers, you should do it the easy way, not the hard way.

Comment: The last part of this seems at odds with dockers own documentation which offers information on how to modify iptables for docker and similar https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I found the reason, it was docker's iptables rules that were interfering with his normal work

Answer (score 0):

The ip source changed because the packet went through a [NAT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) setup with [iptables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) by docker.

This is done because other machines on your network (and the internet) do not know where to find IP addresses inside your docker network.  So instead every outgoing packet it changed to have your host machine's IP.